# how to filter api data with only image avialble

Tags: javascript, api

i have api calls , in which some image address have image,other dont have valid image.. i want only valid images shoed on webpage based on status code

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code for above quiestion

```
var container=document.createElement("div")
container.className="container"
var row=document.createElement("div")
row.classList.add("row","m-3")
container.append(row);


var res=fetch("https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json",);
res.then((data)=>data.json())
.then((data1)=>foo(data1))
.catch((error)=>console.log(error));

function foo(data1){
    for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
        
        row.innerHTML+=
        `<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <img src="${data1[i].image_link}" class="card-img-top" alt="contry flag">
  
  <div class="card-body">
   <h5>${data1[i].brand}</h5>
   <p>$${data1[i].price}</p>
   <p>${data1[i].name}</p>
   <p>${data1[i].product_link}</p>
  </div>
  <a href=${data1[i].description} class="btn btn-primary" >click to description</a>

</div>
            
        </div>`


    
        
        
    }
}
document.body.append(container)
```

//how to display only valid images on card,ignore if image is not avialable

Comment: Your JS is the same as your HTML. That can't be right. But you can easily just listen for the `error` event on `Image` (or `<img />`, same thing) elements to find out if something went wrong and then remove/hide them.

Comment: This is the same question you asked a few hours ago -> Does this answer your question? [how to display valid image from api calls by status code 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202602/how-to-display-valid-image-from-api-calls-by-status-code-200)